# Irreducible unitary representations of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb R)$ from those of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, harmonic-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$In the case of a non-Archimedean local field $\mathbb F$, one may reduce the representation theory of $\SL(n,\mathbb F)$ to that of $\GL(n,\mathbb F)$. My question is that is there a similar result for the real number field $\mathbb R$? More precisely, if each irreducible unitary representation of $\SL(n,\mathbb R)$ is a constituent of the restriction to  $\SL(n,\mathbb R)$ of an irreducible unitary representation of $\GL(n,\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Since positive reals have unique $n$'th roots, the subgroup $GL^{>0}(n,\mathbb R)$ with positive determinant is the product $SL(n, \mathbb R) \times \mathbb R^{>0}$, with the map given by dividing by the $n$'th root of the determinant. So you can tensor your representation by any unitary character of $ \mathbb R^{>0}$ and then induce to $GL(n,\mathbb R)$, producing either an irreducible unitary representation or a sum of two of them.

Comment: Thanks Will!  May ask one more question that why a sum of two? In the complex case,  it seems to be a sum of n irreducible representations.

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? The general phenomenon is that an irreducible representation of $SL_n(F)$ extends to one irreducible representation of $F^\times SL_n(F)$ for each way of extending the central character of $\mu_n(F)$ to $F^\times$. Then each of those can be induced up to $GL_n(F)$. If we induce up to $GL_n(F)$ and restrict back to $SL_n(F)$, we'll get a sum of $k$ irreducible representations, where $k$ is the index of $F^\times SL_n(F)$ in $GL_n(F)$.

Comment: Those $k$ irreducible representations can come from between $1$ and $k$ irreps of $GL_n(F)$, each of which is a sum of between $1$ and $k$ irreps of $SL_n(F)$, with the total summing to $k$. For $F = \mathbb R$, $k=1$ or $2$ depending on if $n$ is odd or even. For $F = \mathbb C$, $k=1$, and I'm not sure where $n$ comes from.